# How to avoid Session hijacking in asp.net where IP address assign to clients dynamic

Tags: asp.net

I want to prevent session hijacking in my application.I refer this below link where session is check w.r.t IP address and works fine but the situation where IP is assigned dynamic on user machine it fails.
Anyone have proper solution to prevent such attack.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/suthish_nair/how-to-avoid-session-hijacking-in-web-applications/

Comment: ASP.NET Sessions are based on a cookie, not ip address. The question is flawed.

Comment: You've better to implement the CSRF token

Comment: The article is flawed. It's possible for the IP address to change from one connection to the next if there is some form of NAT device in the path. Also, sorry, but I don't see this happening much, if at all, if you're using SSL.